# Spring Security - read users from Tomcat realm

Tags: java, spring-security, tomcat7

I would like to use Tomcat realm + Spring Security to authenticate users.
However I am getting StackOverflowError:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:102)
    java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:89)
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:421)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:421)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.authenticate(Unknown Source)
```

Note that every time I access a web page, I get a different stack trace (the stack trace is truncated differently)

I guess I am doing something fundamentally wrong...
My current config:

tomcat users:

```
   <tomcat-users>
     <role rolename="ROLE_USER"/>
     <role rolename="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
     <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

server.xml:

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

Spring Security config:

```
 @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().jee().mappableRoles("USER", "ADMIN") //not sure is ROLE_USER should be used... according to javadoc ROLE_ prefix is added automatically
                    .and().httpBasic();
        }
```

**Spring version:** 4.0.2.RELEASE

**Spring Security version:** 3.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: Could you provide which version of Spring and Spring security you are using?

Comment: Spring version: 4.0.2.RELEASE
Spring Security version: 3.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: Have you configured an AuthenticationManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've hit: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2515. It indicates that your configuration is incorrect.

Comment: you are right - I had was missing some additional configuration in web.xml